# Как сделать Vue JS <router-link> не ссылкой, а простым элементом?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Помогите, пожалуйста, лаконично организовать компонент Vue.

Есть параметр isLink который по условию будет рендерить ссылку router-link или просто div

```
<template>
  <router-link v-if="isLink" :to="link">
    // Какая то вёрстка...
  </router-link>
  <div v-else>
    // Какая то вёрстка...
  </div>
</template>
```

Мне хочется сделать так, что бы не нужно было дублировать код внутри элементов и всё записывать в один  но при этом чтобы это была не ссылка при условии `isLink === false`, а простой div.
Примерно так:

```
<template>
  <router-link v-if="isLink" :to="link">
    /* Если isLink === false, 
       то router-link будет обычный div 
    */
    
    // Какая то вёрстка...
  </router-link>
</template>
```

Comment: там есть параметр `tag`

Comment: Да, все верно. Но даже при условии добавления параметра tag="div" элемент все равно работает как link, а мне нужно чтобы он был простым элементом, а не ссылка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так будет правильнее

```
<template>
  <component :is="tag">{{ text }}</component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["isLink", "text"],
  computed: {
    tag() {
      return this.isLink ? "router-link" : "div";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Если использование компонента должно быть максимально простым — этот способ отлично подойдёт. Однако этот способ не применим если контент должен отличаться при разных значениях `isLink`. Возможно, стоит использовать `<slot>` вместо `{{ text }}`?

Comment: Возможно так же следует уточнить в ответе что это пример отдельного готового отдельного компонента, который можно будет позже использовать как замену `<router-link>`?

Comment: @7-zete-7, ниче не понял. Это же минимальный код, который решает проблему. Если при решении задачи заказчика надо будет слот -  напишите слот.

Comment: В вопросе так и написано _"Какая то вёрстка..."_, что подразумевает наличие не просто текста, а каких-то тегов. Прочтите вопрос внимательнее.

Comment: Постарайтесь расписать как должен работать код из этого ответа. За готовое решение автор, конечно, скажет спасибо, однако заходящие по этому вопросу люди в будущем не смогут понять что происходит в этом коде.

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#tag) Vue написано:

> Иногда необходимо чтобы `<router-link>` отображался другим тегом, например `<li>`. В таком случае мы можем использовать входной параметр `tag`, чтобы указать нужный тег, и он всё равно будет прослушивать события click для навигации.

Если целью является стилизовать элементы в зависимости от выбранного роута, то корректнее и проще будет использовать [свойства объекта Route](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-route). На основе этих свойств можно будет описать рендеринг необходимых стилизованных элементов.

```
<template>
  <router-link v-if="isLink" :to="link"></router-link>
  <div v-else :class="{ 'some-class': $route.path === link.path }"></div>
</template>
```

Если это является проблемой, то можно вынести этот код в отдельный компонент и использовать уже непосредственно новый компонент, у которого будет отсутствовать дублирование элементов.

Comment: Этот же подход, все равно предполагает дублирование кода. И вообще не расширяемый

Comment: @Дмытрык, проблему он решает. Если есть какие-либо предложению в контексте этого ответа — буду рад улучшить ответ

Comment: Как улучшить, написал отдельным ответом